# How to refresh dependent dual listbox in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, multi-select, dependent-picklist, lightning-duallistbox

[image: LWC]

The attached image is an LWC, in which Category is a controlling picklist (Combobox) and Sub Categ is the Dependent Picklist.

Eg. Category 1: Sub Categ 1,2,3
Category 2: Sub Categ 2,3

I am storing Selected Sub Category values in an array and I want to use it further. The array variable is set with selected values in the onChange method of dual-listbox.

Here the problem is initially if I select **Category=1** and Select ***Sub Category = 1,2,3.***
But then I remember oh I wanted to select **Category = 2**

Here what happens is when I change the Category, Sub Category selected values automatically changed to 2,3. But I am not able to set those values to an array variable. The array will still hold previous values 1,2,3

Answer (score 0):

You can either wait a tick and update the value, or you can manually filter the array when you update the dependent values.

## Wait A Tick

```
this.availableOptions = filteredOptions;
setTimeout(() => { 
  this.availableOptions = this.template.querySelector('lightning-dual-listbox').value
})
```

After changing the options, the value attribute should update, which we can then copy.

## Filter On Update

```
this.availableOptions = filteredOptions;
this.selectedOptions = this.selectedOptions.filter(
  selectedValue => filteredOptions.find(
    availableOption => availableOption.value === selectedValue
  )
)
```

Basically, for each previously selected option, we see if we can find that value in the new list of options, and if not, remove it from the list.

Comment: Thanks.. I tried the timeout option in onChange function of Category , but it didn't work. It still returns the old selected values. And second point I didn't understand much. Can you please elaborate.